# Correct usage of spring annotation

Tags: java, spring

I'm very new in spring, and wonder if configurations below is a correct approach when using annotation. I notice at least 2 problems :

1. In application-context.xml, I still have to configure bean `<bean id= ...>...</bean>` to inject hibernate session factory, instead of using annotation
2. Sample codes below always returns null on main()

Can you give your suggestion?
Thank you

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;IFEXISTS=TRUE" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.cupidocreative.hibernate.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> -->
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cupidocreative.hibernate.dao" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="postWorksheetDAO" class="com.cupidocreative.hibernate.dao.PostWorksheetDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

PostWorksheetDAO.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PostWorksheetDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    ....hibernate operations
}
```

PostWorksheetService.java

```
@Service
public class PostWorksheetService {

    @Autowired
    private PostWorksheetDAO postWorksheetDAO;

    public PostWorksheetDAO getPostWorksheetDAO() {
        return postWorksheetDAO;
    }

}
```

Main class, always returns null

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //PostWorksheetService postWorksheetService = new PostWorksheetService();
    // should use this
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");

    PostWorksheetService postWorksheetService = context.getBean(PostWorksheetService.class);
    System.out.println(postWorksheetService.getPostWorksheetDAO());
    System.out.println(postWorksheetService.getPostWorksheetDAO());
}
```

Comment: You don't have a `@ComponentScan` annotation which is required (among other things) to get things running. If you're using annotations, you don't need `application-context.xml`. Read the documentation, it's all there.

Comment: Hi, sorry but i don't understand why this is marked as duplicate. I think the problem occurs because i use "new" operator to create my service. So i put a @Service on service class, but how can i use service class from main, if i can't instantiate it? Also, on my application-context seems dirty because it still has bean declaration, while i've annotated dao class and use component-scan

Comment: @Kayaman i did some google and i think i'll stick on application-context.xml. my google result is not really clear qnd most tutorial use an xml file. Is this a problem that cause null? Thanks anyway

Comment: solved, should not use "new" operator when calling bean on main class